# log4j.LogManager.callerClass crashed on JRE 11 and 16 except JRE 8

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

In order to solve the [security vulnerability](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), I have updated Log4j from 2.8.1 into 2.17.0 on pom.xml of Maven as below, building with Java 8.

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
-            <version>2.8.1</version>
+            <version>2.17.0</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
-            <version>2.8.1</version>
+            <version>2.17.0</version>
         </dependency>
```

While my Jar file worked well on JRE 8, it crashed on JRE 11 and 16 throwing the below exception.

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
...
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No class provided, and an appropriate one cannot be found.
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.callerClass(LogManager.java:573)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:598)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:585)
...
```

How can I resolve the error?

### My goal is

Built with Java 8 and pom.xml, the Jar file works well on JRE 8, 11 and 16.

### Details of pom.xml

Here is the details of pom.xml in part. I'm sorry to mask some blocks due to the confidentiality.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>xx.xx.xxxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxx-parent</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>xxxxxxxx</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
   </dependencies>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>jna-platform</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>xxxxxxxx</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First please show full pom file...furthermore you should upgrade to 2.17.0 log4j... see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added two sections: **Details of pom.xml** and **About log4j version** @khmarbaise

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of official advice you need..read the page up to the end... Furthermore the part about multi release is for creating a jar ..do you want to create jar which is a multi release jar? If no you don't need it...

Comment: There are two options. Using JDK8 and build with that...that will run on JDK8+ Or you build with JDK17 and use `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>`...

Comment: What looks strange is that you are using an ancient version of surefire -plugin (2.12?) ... and skip tests? Why?Don't you have any unit tests?

Comment: I deleted **About log4j version** and **What I have tried** because they may confuse you. What I want to do is to upgrade Log4j into 2.17.0 and to build Java files which can run on JRE 8, 11 and 16. In addition, I don't need a multi release jar (after your comment, I found that **What I have tried** was at conflict with my goal). @khmarbaise

Comment: The above my comment is the reply for yesterday your comment. @khmarbaise